# node.js mysql not returning results

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback, socket.io, return

I am working with socket.io and node.js developing login system, but getting error while I am authenticating user:

```
function checkUsername(username){
//  console.log("checking username "+username+" in database");

        var sql = "SELECT username FROM users where username = ?";
        var checkUser;

        //execute query
        db.query(sql, [username], function (err, result,fields) {
            if (err) 
                console.log(err);
            else{           
                //gets found records length/quantity
                checkUser = result.length;
                console.log("username "+username+" result: "+checkUser);
                return checkUser;
            }
        });
}
```

I'm getting `undefined` in return, in short there is nothing being returned.

Comment: Have you logged result? What do you get?

Comment: Also you should move `var checkUser` into your else statement. You are extending the scope for no reason.

Comment: I would assume that result is actually an object like this `{prop: "data", "another": [1,2,3,4]}`. And getting objectValue.length is equal to undefined. This is what you get. Try console.log(result) and you should see similar output.

Comment: i am getting correct results in console it is 0 or 1. However i am not able to return the results. It returns undefined whenever i call the function : checkUsername("awais");